# FileNotFoundException when using DistributedCache to access MapFile

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, cloudera, distributed-cache

I am using hadoop cdf4.7 run in yarn mode. There is a MapFile in `hdfs://test1:9100/user/tagdict_builder_output/part-00000`
and it has two file `index` and  `data`

I used the following code to add it to distributedCache:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Path tagDictFilePath = new Path("hdfs://test1:9100/user/tagdict_builder_output/part-00000");
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(tagDictFilePath.toUri(), conf);
Job job = new Job(conf);
```

And initialize a MapFile.Reader at setup of Mapper：

```
        @Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {



            Path[] localFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
            if (localFiles != null && localFiles.length > 0 && localFiles[0] != null) {
                String mapFileDir = localFiles[0].toString();
                LOG.info("mapFileDir " + mapFileDir);
                FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
                reader = new MapFile.Reader(fs, mapFileDir, context.getConfiguration());
            }
            else {
                throw new IOException("Could not read lexicon file in DistributedCache");
            }
}
```

But it throws FileNotFoundException:

```
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /home/mps/cdh/local/usercache/mps/appcache/application_1405497023620_0045/container_1405497023620_0045_01_000012/part-00000/data
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:824)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1704)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.MapFile$Reader.createDataFileReader(MapFile.java:452)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.MapFile$Reader.open(MapFile.java:426)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.MapFile$Reader.<init>(MapFile.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.MapFile$Reader.<init>(MapFile.java:405)
        at aps.Cdh4MD5TaglistPreprocessor$Vectorizer.setup(Cdh4MD5TaglistPreprocessor.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:756)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:338)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:160)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:155)
```

I've also tried `/user/tagdict_builder_output/part-00000` as path,or use a symbol link. But these do not work either.How to solve this?Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As it says [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-input-distributed-cache.html):

> Distributed Cache associates the cache files to the current working directory of the mapper and reducer using symlinks.

So you should try to access your files through the `File` object:

```
File f = new File("./part-00000");
```

**EDIT1**

My last suggestion:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(tagDictFilePath.toString() + "#cache-file"), conf);
DistributedCache.createSymlink(conf);
...
// in mapper
File f = new File("cache-file");
```